# Custom ticks failing with Frame

Tags: plotting, ticks

I know I can manipulate ticks:

```
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1.5], x], {x, -7, 7}, 
   Ticks -> {{
     {-6, "-6σ"}, {-5, "-5σ"}, {-4, "-4σ"}, {-3, "-3σ"}, {-2, "-2σ"}, {-1, "-σ"}, 
     {1, "σ"}, {2, "2σ"}, {3, "3σ"}, {4, "4σ"}, {5, "5σ"}, {6, "6σ"}
 }}]
```

But the ticks disappear when I add `Frame -> True`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing wrong as such... only for [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Frame.html) you need the [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html) option (to add some spice see another way to get your ticks):

```
xticks = {#, StringReplace[ToString[# σ], " " -> ""]} & /@Range[-6, 6];

Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1.5], x], {x, -7, 7}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xticks, xticks}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Typographic note. I suggest replacing `StringReplace[ToString[# σ], " " -> ""]` with `StringReplace[ToString[# σ], " " -> "\[VeryThinSpace]"]`. The difference is subtle, but inserting a very-thin-space really makes the tick labels look better.

Comment: @m_goldberg agreed - I just wanted to reproduce the OP´s ticks 1:1. Without that, generating the ticks could be done more straightforward, too.