# ListPlot with redundant labels for tick marks

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is it possible to have two sets of labels for the $x$-axis tick marks using `ListPlot`?  For example, could we have tick marks labels: {1,2,3,4,...}, and then right below these labels, the values for the powers of two: {2,4,8,16,...}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point :

```
data = Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 10}];
ListPlot[data, Ticks -> {Table[{i, Column[{i, Style[2^i, Red]}]}, {i, 10}], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But what to do if I need a frame and grid lines! Setting Frame -> True kills custom labeling (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LabelingTwoDimensionalGraphics.html). Nevermind, just found an answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32831/custom-ticks-failing-with-frame