# FontSize problematic when used in LabelStyle

Tags: plotting, bugs, fonts, labeling

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Consider the following few examples, each producing a trivial graphic object:

---

```
Graphics[Circle[], PlotLabel -> "X", Frame -> True]
```

It is a circle in a frame, with a label, **naturally works fine**.

---

```
Graphics[Circle[], LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "X"]
```

All the same, but now we define the size of the labels. **Works okay.**

---

Now the problem, try defining FontSize through, e.g. FontSize->Large:

```
Graphics[Circle[], LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> Large}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "X"]
```

**This gives a complain** "specified setting for FontSize" cannot be used.

---

I would guess, maybe the syntax for fonts has changed in V10, **but** the problem does not appear if no plotlabel is specified (i.e. the labels on the frame are displayed properly):

```
Graphics[Circle[], LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> Large}, Frame -> True]
```

**This works okay.**

---

What is more, even in documentation one examplifies using FontSize in a construction like this:

```
Table[Text[Style["ABC", FontSize -> p]], {p, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}]
```

**To summarize**: It looks as if when construction LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> Large} goes together with PlotLabel->"Something", an error pops up.

**Question**: Can anyone reproduce it? (**done**, see comments to Lou's answer) Is it an intended behavior? If so, why?

I am using ubuntu 14.04, MMA 10.0.1

**Edit**: And yes, I have tried it on MMA 9.0, Windows 7, and the problem does not appear there.

**Edit 2**: **Added a summary of the problem in a separate answer.**

Comment: Note: `LabelStyle -> {"Large"}` works on both the frame and the `PlotLabel`.  (`"Large"` is a style defined in core.nb.  I'm not sure why `Large` without the quotes fails on `PlotLabel`.  Bug, perhaps?)

Comment: Strange, indeed. By the way Graphics[Circle[], LabelStyle -> Larger, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "X"] works (Larger instead of Large)

Comment: Sent a message to WRI support...

Comment: Still there in 10.0.2

Comment: The style `"Label"` has the setting `FontSize->"Small"` defined in Core.nb and leads to the same error when `"Label"` is used as the `LabelStyle` in `Graphics`. (At least in V10.0.2.)  It seems to be the only style in Core.nb that has `FontSize` defined this way.

Comment: Still there in 11.0.1 as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Some final remarks** on this, concluding from nice communications with Wolfram support.

A command of this form is generally intended to work and to produce a label in large size:

```
Graphics[Disk[], LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> Large}, PlotLabel -> "X"]
```

It doesn't however, and **it is a known bug since MMA version 9** (that is, at least in V9 and V10). In V10 it produces an error message, whereas in V9 it does not work as intended.

Some workarounds have been mentioned in comments and answers, here is a **workaround summary**:

- Use FrameLabel instead of PlotLabel (credit to Lou). Though not identical, this might serve as a substitute
- Use {FontSize -> 24} instead of {FontSize -> Large}, or analagously for other sizes
- Use {FontSize -> "Large"} instead of {FontSize -> Large}. It happens to work because of default style definition for a style called "Large" (indeed in Core.nb), but it will not work generally, e.g. {FontSize -> "Tiny"} does not work.
- Further examples of working commands might be found in the answer by Mr.Wizard

So much for it, and let's hope to see the bug fixed in the future versions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for making us aware of this problem.

Momentarily exploring this myself I note that these also work:

```
LabelStyle -> {"Large"}

LabelStyle -> {"Tiny"}

LabelStyle -> {24}

LabelStyle -> Directive["Large"]

LabelStyle -> Directive["Tiny"]

LabelStyle -> Directive[24]
```

Hopefully this is useful information to someone encountering the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your addition! I will refer to your answer in my summary post.

Answer (score 2):

I can repeat the error with 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014), but 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013) does not seem to exhibit this behavior.

Frame labels are affected by LabelStyle, i.e., as a Workaround one can use:

```
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> "X", LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Large]]
```

works as expected.

[image]

Whether an error or a bug or a glitch, `PlotLabel` and `FrameLabel` as such must be distinguished carefully:

[image]

See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32831/custom-ticks-failing-with-frame) Q/A.

Comment: @Alexey Bobrick, Yep, the same problem with 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014), I showed a workaround. With `Directive` you do not have an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting point! I guess, the thing is that it works okay with FrameLabel, but not with PlotLabel. Directive doesn't seem to help though with PlotLabels.

Comment: This way, there are two workarounds indeed: one is to use FrameLabel, another - to specify fontsize in absolute units. Still, I wonder, if it is an intended behavior.

Comment: though, maybe I could ask you to edit your answer a tiny bit, for it might mislead people into thinking that the problem is not present.