# How to label Ticks in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, webmathematica, labeling

I have some discrete data and want to make a density plot as

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1,  4}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

> [image: Output of ListDensityPlot]

What if I want to add *"t"* along vertical axis as *1.0t 1.5t 2.0t, 2.5t, 3.0t, 3.5t 4.0t*, where *t* is some constant.

Comment: Have a look at `FrameTicks` and search the site for `custom ticks`, which should help you already, e.g. here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32831/131.

Comment: Since there are so many helpful answers, I´d go for re-opening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}};

ticks = {#, ToString[# t]} & /@ Range[4]

ListDensityPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Closer to what I wanted, and I tried to modify your suggestion according to what was my target. I obtained the required things. Thanks

Comment: @zenith The site might get better answers if you wait a little longer to accept.  Often 24 hours are suggested.  Some people skip questions with accepted answers.

Comment: alright, i may wait then 24 hours

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this:

```
t = Pi/2;
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 
   4}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, t, 2 t, 3 t}, None}, {{0, t, 2 t, 3 t}, None}}
 ]
```

[image]

or like this :

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1,1,1,1},{1,2,1,2},{1,1,3,1},{1,2,1,4}},
Frame->True,
FrameLabel->{"a","b"},
FrameTicks->
{{{{0,"Null"},{t,"t"},{2t,"2 t"},{3t,"3 t"}},None},
{{{0,"Null"},{t,"t"},{2t,"2 t"},{3t,"3 t"}},None}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was what I wanted

```
  data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}};

ticks = {{1, "t"}, {2, "2 t"}, {3, "3 t"}, {4, "4 t"}}

ListDensityPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"},  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]